# When will our published paper appear in Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

Our paper was published on 28 December 2021 in MDPI. It was written that after 24 hours metrics are available. Still it is not appeared in Google Scholar? Can I add it manually? What is the difference between automatic and manual addition?

Comment: My latest publication showed up in my Google Scholar 4 days after what IEEE gives as the publication date. I'm not sure if it's faster or slower for MDPI but I suggest waiting a couple more days if possible.

Comment: Thanks. It will be automatically update right?

Comment: Yes, it will be added automatically to Google Scholar.

Comment: Whether your paper will be linked to your account automatically (if you have one) depends on your settings.